# some time delayed functon is shunt in flutter

Tags: flutter, sms, delay

hello I tried to run code after received sms, if sms isn't reveived before 60s I show an alertdialog. Currently my problem is, when I send some sms ( about 20 ) my alert dialog is show directly after press the sms sending button without waiting the 60s of delay.

Here is my complet exemple:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sms/sms.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 // This widget is the root of your application.
    @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: new ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: new SettingsPage()
   );
   }
  }
class SettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_SettingsPageState createState() => new _SettingsPageState();
}

class _SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {
  bool visibility_waiting;
  String group_last_sms;
  SmsMessage _lastMessage = new SmsMessage('', '');


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    visibility_waiting=false;
    new SmsReceiver().onSmsReceived.listen((SmsMessage msg) { //create an sms listener

      if (msg.address == "your phone number") {  //for the test, I wait to receive my owm message to make action
        setState(() {
         _lastMessage = msg;
      });

        RegExp regExp = new RegExp(  // regexp function to extract particular string in the sms and make an action
      r"(test)",
        );
       var match = regExp.firstMatch(_lastMessage.body); // listen the last sms
       group_last_sms = match.group(1);
       if (group_last_sms=="test"){
         setState(() {
_changed(false, "waiting");  // hide visibility of text and circular progress indicator
visibility_waiting=false;
      });
    }
  }
 });

  }
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(

    body: Stack (


      children: <Widget>[
        _buildWidgetContent(), // widget with my raised button , to send test sms

        visibility_waiting?Positioned( // when i press raised button , I show progres indicator, If "test" sms is received I hide circular progress indicator,

            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.lightBlue),
              ),
            ),


        ): new Container(),


        visibility_waiting? // when i press raised button , I show text, If "test" sms is received I hide text,
        new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column (
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(80.0),),
                Text('sending sms, please wait', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 18.0,
                )),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ): new Container(),
      ],
    )
   );
  }

 void _changed(bool visibility, String field) { // function for hide or show circular progress indicator
setState(() {
  if (field == "waiting"){
    visibility_waiting = visibility;
   }
  }
  );
 }

  @override
Widget _buildWidgetContent( ) {

return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
    ),
    body: new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[

        new Center(
           child : new RaisedButton(

                onPressed: ()
            {
              visibility_waiting=true;
              _changed(true, "waiting");
              handleSignIn();

              new SmsSender().sendSms(new SmsMessage(
                  "your phone number","test;" )
              );
            }
            )

        )
      ],
    ));
   }

 Future<Null> handleSignIn() async {

await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds:20));{  //wait the sms
  if (  visibility_waiting ==true){  // if sms is not received before 60s  _chargement  is true so I show an error dialog
    setState(() {
      visibility_waiting =false;
      _changed(false, "waiting");
      erreurcommunication();
    }
    );
  }
}
}


  Future<Null>erreurcommunication() async {  // alerte dialog when I have waited more than 60s

  await showDialog<String>(
     context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    child: new AlertDialog(
      title: new Text("Problème de reseau"),
      content: new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text("veuillez reessayer"),

            new OutlineButton(
                child: new  Text('ok', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                onPressed: (){
                  setState(() { {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }
                  }
                  );
                },
                highlightElevation: 4.0,
                borderSide: new BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.grey.shade300),
                highlightColor  : Colors.white,
                shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
            ),
            Container (  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
   );
 }
```

}

You can copy past this code and try with your phone number. After about 20 press the delay function shunt the 60s of delays and show the alert dialog.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I tried to isolate more the issue. I have remove the sms function and I add a delay to simulate the sms reception. Result : same issue,some time erreurcommunication() is call before 20s of delays.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


 void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: new ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: new SettingsPage()
 );
 }
 }
class SettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 _SettingsPageState createState() => new _SettingsPageState();
}

class _SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {
bool visibility_waiting;


@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
visibility_waiting=false;
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(

    body: Stack (


       children: <Widget>[
        _buildWidgetContent(), // widget with my raised button , to send test sms

          visibility_waiting?Positioned( // when i press raised button , I show progres indicator, If "test" sms is received I hide circular progress indicator,

            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.lightBlue),
              ),
            ),


        ): new Container(),


        visibility_waiting? // when i press raised button , I show text, If "test" sms is received I hide text,
        new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column (
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(80.0),),
                Text('sending sms, please wait', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 18.0,
                )),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ): new Container(),
      ],
    )
   );
  } 

  void _changed(bool visibility, String field) { // function for hide or show circular progress indicator
setState(() {
  if (field == "waiting"){
    visibility_waiting = visibility;
  }
}
);
 }

 @override
 Widget _buildWidgetContent( ) {

return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
    ),
    body: new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[

        new Center(
           child : new RaisedButton(
                onPressed: ()
            {
              setState(() {
                visibility_waiting=true;
                _changed(true, "waiting");
                handleSignIn1(); //waiting 2s before hide progress indicator 
              });
            }
            )

        )
      ],
    ));
   }
 Future<Null> handleSignIn1() async {

  await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds:2));{  //simulate the sms received

  visibility_waiting =false;
  _changed(false, "waiting");
                handleSignIn2(); // waitig 20s before show error dialog. the issue = error dialog is show before 20s 

   }
  }
Future<Null> handleSignIn2() async {

await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds:20));{  //wait the sms 20s
  if (  visibility_waiting ==true){  // in this case visibility_waiting is always false before 20s, so erreurcommunication() can't be call. currently some time erreurcommunication() is call directly after press raisedbutton
    setState(() {
      visibility_waiting =false;
      _changed(false, "waiting");
      erreurcommunication();
    }
    );
  }
}
}

 Future<Null>erreurcommunication() async {  // alerte dialog when I have waited more than 60s

await showDialog<String>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    child: new AlertDialog(
      title: new Text("Problème de reseau"),
      content: new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text("veuillez reessayer"),

            new OutlineButton(
                child: new  Text('ok', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                onPressed: (){
                  setState(() { {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }
                  }
                  );
                },
                highlightElevation: 4.0,
                borderSide: new BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.grey.shade300),
                highlightColor  : Colors.white,
                shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
            ),
            Container (  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
   );
 } 
}
```

Comment: If I reduce the second delay, error is show more quickly. I think I need to close the timer or some thing like this or complet the timer. but I don't know how to do this

Comment: I have create timer instead of delayed and problem seems to be solved with timer.cancel().